# opening the last page raises "That page contains no resuls" error when a second "next-page" button is added in django

Tags: python, django, pagination

The django pagination works well.

Main html for pagination:

```
<div class="pagination">
        {% if entries.has_previous %}
        <a class=left-holder href="?page={{ entries.previous_page_number }}"> <img class=left-arrow
                src="{% static 'icons\leftarrow.png' %}" alt="leftarrow"></a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if not request.user_agent.is_mobile %}
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="dropdown()" class="dropbtn">{{entries.number}}<span class=arrow-down><span
                            class=spanito>&#9660;</span></button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    {% for i in page_list %}
                    <a href="?page={{i}}"><span {% if i == entries.number %} class=exception {% endif %}>{{i}}</span></a>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="phone_select()" class="dropbtn">{{entries.number}}<span class=arrow-down><span
                        class=spanito>&#9660;</span></button>

        {% endif %}
        {% if entries.has_next %}
        <a class=next href="?page={{ entries.next_page_number }}"> <img class=right-arrow
                src="{% static 'icons\rightarrow.png' %}" alt="rightarrow"></a>
        {% endif %}
        <a href="?page={{ entries.paginator.num_pages }}"><button
                class=last-page>{{entries.paginator.num_pages}}</button></a>
        <b>-</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added a pop-up selection feature for mobile only and for practicality I also added another "next-page" button to the pop-up menu.

Pop-up html from base.html:

```
<div class="overlay6" id="overlay6">
        <div id=fullscrean3>
            <div class=scrollable-div id=scrollable-div>
                {% for i in page_list %}
                    {% if i == entries.number %}
                    <a class=scroll-select id=exception2 href="?page={{i}}"><span id=exception>{{i}}</span></a>
                    {% else %}
                    <a class=scroll-select href="?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <button class=button-prevp onclick="kapat('overlay3') ">prev page</button>
            <a href="?page={{ entries.next_page_number }}"><button class=button-nextp></button>next page</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the second next page button is included the last page becomes inaccessible and raises "That page contains no resuls" error.

Error report:

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\blog\templates\base.html, error at line 75

    <a href="?page={{ entries.next_page_number }}"><button class=button-nextp></button>next page</button></a>
```

In the meantime all other pages remain accesible.

Comment: base.html does not have `{% if entries.has_next %}`, so it's always trying to display the button, even when you're already on the last page.

Comment: That's right Mr. Gordon, thank you a lot.